# Get all IPv6 addresses on all interfaces (Windows)

Tags: windows-xp, ipv6

I have a solution using WMI, unfortunately only on Windows Vista and above. On WinXP/2003 WMI will only return IPv4 adresses. Is there any way to get all assigned addresses including IPv6 ones on WinXP?

Adt: No .NET, just WMI or WinAPI please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some more hours of googling, I finally found [GetAdaptersAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915.aspx)() in the MSDN library.

Sometimes you just use the wrong search terms it seems.