# Windows: Programmatically retrieve manually configured IPv6 address

Tags: windows, winapi, networking, registry, ipv6

I can retrieve the manually configured IPv4 Address of a Network Adapter (including disabled ones) by reading the *IPAddress* value from the following registry key

```
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{Adapter-Guid}
```

Is there a similar way to retrieve the IPv6 address? Or do you have any other suggestion to get the manually configured IPv6 address in code?

Comment: Yes you can do it in code. You should stop reading the registry for this, and use the API. Why did you decide to use the registry? Was there a specific reason?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214653/get-all-ipv6-addresses-on-all-interfaces-windows

Comment: Yes, I also need the configured IP addresses of disabled Adapters.

Comment: It doesn't state that in the question

Answer (score 1):

Please **don't** read system settings directly from **Registry**. You will end up having **compatibility issues** as the configuration/settings location(s) could be different on different versions of OS. Use `GetAdaptersAddresses()` API function on Windows to do that.

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot use GetAdaptersAddresses in this case, because it does not return any disabled Adapter. I also need to get the Information of disabled ones

Comment: Even with the `GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_ALL_INTERFACES` flag specified?

Comment: Yes, this flag does not change the behavior for inclusion of disabled interfaces. Same thing with WMI using Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration